# Astro experimental key: `viewTransitions`. Invalid

Tags: javascript, astrojs

astro version 2.9.1

```
export default defineConfig({
  experimental: {
    viewTransitions: true
  },
  integrations: [react(), tailwind()],
});
```

how is it invalid
i tryed to use assets as its also an experimental feature and it didnt give an error but viewTransition did
is it only me or viewTransition is not yet useable